# make input fields and responsive

Tags: html, css

I have 3 element - input field, dropmenu and a button. After few hours of trying, I still unable to place them in a row and responsive. I used float but it seem to break when I resize the windows.

```
<form>
    <div class="tasksInput">
        <input placeholder="Insert" type="text" class="form-control " />
    </div>
    <select>
        <option value="">Option</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit </button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VgwL8/1/

Comment: Can you define "break"?

Comment: @Scott I use float and messed up with bootstrap, so it doesn't work basically.

Comment: You are not being descriptive. "Doesn't work" also doesn't describe how things fail and what you expect to see.

Comment: @Scott Leo know what I want..

Comment: The "twitter-bootstrap" tag is meaningless here as this question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @OregonJeff no one gave a solution of bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FIXED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VgwL8/7/)

I gave the input wrapper margin in is left side for both select and submit button.
and add wrapper to  button + select + position absolute that relative to the form.

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="tasksInput">
        <input placeholder="Insert" type="text" class="form-control " />
    </div>
    <div class="submit-and-options">
        <select>
            <option value="">Option</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form{position:relative;}
.tasksInput{margin-right:150px;}
.submit-and-options{position:absolute; right:0; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a most flexible and modern solution you can use Flexbox model of CSS3, I have updated your jsfiddle [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VgwL8/5/)

using:

```
.flexBox {
    display: -webkit-box; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box; /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex; /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.droptown {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 1; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: 1; /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 1; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 1; /* NEW, */
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.flexChild {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2; /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 2; /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -webkit-flex: 2; /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 2; /* IE 10 */
    flex: 2; /* NEW, */
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
.tasksInput{
    display:inline;

}
.form-control
{
    display:inline;
width:100px;
}
```

hope it will help..

Comment: what if I want the form-control to be 100%, stretch to its parent width? I tried with fix width, I don't want that.

Comment: den it will be on whole screen..??then why you want to 100% if you want all others on same line??sorry din get you..will you explain little bit more..as want to help you..:)

Comment: I mean the input field stretch 100%, but it doesn't work that way coz it pushed the 2 elements down if I use width 100%

Comment: yes coz then there will b no space for others..tell me why you want to use 100%..and can you use parent div and put form inside and then use media queies for responsive..:)

Comment: now what wrong i did so i got negative marks?? -_- i really hate those people who dnt try to help bt always give negative marks..huhhh